# Parse notification service with listview crashing

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, push-notification

I'm just new to android development & I'm facing the problem

I grabbed listview from php/json (mysql output) into android device & its working fine.

For notifications I searched a lot and found GCM is good but bit complicated for me as a started.

I got some easy thing done with Parse Notifications (www.parse.com)

But the problem is, when i put Parse initialize lines in my listview code, the app crashes on pushing notification

here is code for my listview

[ListView Code](http://pastebin.com/vFUbZSJR)

I also tried to put Parse code in service, but still on receiving notification application crashes

and here is how I put parse lines in listview code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Parse.initialize(this, "ctMEM5bnp9OBIgiewrsxewq2IGVGt5NEdH7zaD4TCAd", "zX9pmbsadfsdacwezzC18XDXE16O1j0rdlOfCHzbdayS");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          accessWebService();
    }
```

Please can someone bing these two lines with my listview in manner they won't crash

```
Parse.initialize(this, "ctMEM5bnp9OBIgiewrsxewq2IGVGt5NEdH7zaD4TCAd", "zX9pmbsadfsdacwezzC18XDXE16O1j0rdlOfCHzbdayS");
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: Can you show us the logcat?

Comment: put those line after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  or use pattern that I answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create separate class Application that extends Application   and put it in manifest

```
 import com.parse.Parse;
 import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
 import com.parse.PushService;

 public class Application extends android.app.Application {

   public Application() {

      }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
        // Initialize the Parse SDK.
      Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY");

    // Specify an Activity to handle all pushes by default.
       PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
  }


}
```

Manifiest:

```
<application android:name="com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.Application"
```

See this complete example: **[Github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/tree/master/Android)**